# Mixing past and present in the same sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, verb-agreement

Why are the past and present tenses mixed up in the following sentence?

- Our findings are consistent with a recent comparative study on image processing systems, which also stated that source code for all techniques are not available and that these tools cannot be applied on a new dataset.

As I read this sentence, findings from a recent comparative study in the sentence there is a mixing of the past (`stated`) and then present (`are`).

Tools like Grammarly also do not detect it as an error.

Can anyone please help me to understand why is this sentence correct?

Comment: Why do you think you can't mix tenses in one sentence? You used present continuous and present simple in the same sentence.

Comment: But it is for the `recent comparative study`. Thats why I am confused.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: The study was published in the past, so it's past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The findings are (right now) consistent with what a study found in the past (albeit the recent past). That kind of "mixing of tenses" is perfectly acceptable and grammatically valid, even in formal writing. Tenses for different verbs in a sentence can be different, where the verbs refer to different events, or look at events from different points of view